# Epplus Cell with DateTime type not recognized

Tags: epplus, epplus-4

I have a problem with the DateTime format.
A cell has the following NumberFormat "[$-F800]dddd\,\ mmmm\ dd\,\ yyyy" but it is not recognized as DateTime.

```
if (cells.Value is DateTime){ var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(cells.Value.ToString()); }
```

How can i Get the DataType of Cell?

Best Regards

Comment: Is this related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079530/how-can-i-get-a-datatype-of-a-specific-cell-with-epplus)?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Value`, use `Text`:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");
    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "12/31/2018"; // en-US culture 
    worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "31.12.2018"; // de-CH culture

    // For current culture
    DateTime a = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Text); 

    // For culture other than the current one
    DateTime b = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Text, new CultureInfo("de-CH"));
}
```

Both `a` and `b` have a value of `12/31/2018 12:00:00 AM`.

<sub>(CultureInfo is in System.Globalization namespace).</sub>