# How can i get a DataType of a specific cell with EpPlus?

Tags: epplus, epplus-4

How can i get a DataType of a specific cell with EpPlus while reading an excel file and not the NumberFormat?

Comment: In c# there are 13 data types: `sbyte` `short` `int` `long` `byte` `ushort` `uint` `ulong` `char` `float` `double` `decimal` `bool`. When you say `How can i get a DataType` do you want to receive string: 1)  `"number"` if there are only numbers, dots, commas, or +/- sings 2) `"bool"` if content is `"true"` or `"false"` (case insesitive) 3) `"string"` if anything else? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Excel really only has two data types: string & double. Really, the string type has two subtypes: < 256 chars & >= 256 chars long.
Anything that appears to be a "type" (e.g., short date, currency) is really a style that coerces the display of the value using a format string/pattern.

Comment: @AlexL is correct. My use case is if I try to read a cell with a date formatted as German long date format with the NumberFormat '[$-800]dddd\,\ mmmm\ dd\,\ yyyy' is not recognized as the date

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
var longValDt = xlws.Cells[i, j].Value.GetType().ToString(); // "System.String"
var shortValDt = xlws.Cells[i, j].Value.GetType().ToString().Split('.')[1]; // "String"
var longTextDt = xlws.Cells[i, j].Text.GetType().ToString(); // "System.String"
var shortTextDt = xlws.Cells[i, j].Text.GetType().ToString().Split('.')[1]; // "String"
var format = xlws.Cells[i, j].Style.Numberformat.Format; // "General"
```